# N-dimensional tensor based on std::vector

Tags: c++11

I want to define n-dimensional data structure using std::vector. I have a problem with definition of operator(). Lets have a look at a sample 2D structure

```
class my_data {

public:
  my_data (size_t N, size_t M) : tab(N*M), _N(N), _M(M) {}

  const double& operator() (size_t i, size_t j) const {
     return tab.at(i * M + j);
  }

  double& operator() (size_t i, size_t j) {
     return tab.at(i * M + j);
  }

private:
   std::vector<double> tab;
   size_t _N;
   size_t _M;

};
```

I would like to define such a structures for any dimension using templates , but I don't know if it is possible. So basically what I would like to have is something like that

```
my_data<4> vec (1,2,3,4);
```

defines 4D 'tensor' with sizes 1,2,3,4 (number of all elements 1*2*3*4). You can now access and change values by typing

```
vec (0,0,0,0) = 2.0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below solution uses some of the C++14 and C++1z features, but they can be easily ported to C++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, typename S>
    class my_data;

    template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
    class my_data<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
    {
    public:
        my_data(decltype(Is)... size)
            : t((size * ...)), s{{ size... }}
        {}

        T& operator()(decltype(Is)... i)
        {            
            return t.at(index({{ i... }}));
        }

        const T& operator()(decltype(Is)... i) const
        {            
            return t.at(index({{ i... }}));
        }

    private:
        std::size_t index(const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)>& a) const
        {
            std::size_t ind = a[0];
            for (std::size_t i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
            {
                ind = ind * s[i] + a[i];
            }
            return ind;
        }

        std::vector<T> t;
        const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> s;
    };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using my_data = detail::my_data<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

Test:

```
int main()
{        
    my_data<double, 4> vec(1,2,3,4);
    vec(0,0,0,0) = 2.0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6570aca0f11eb2e2)

[**DEMO (C++11)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6688d68b6f1eafa1)

Comment: Great job @Piotr Skotnicki. I have an extra maybe very dump question: How to make this data structure operate with any data type (not only double)?

Comment: @Bociek I've refined the solution a bit

Comment: Hello @PiotrSkotnicki. I would like to define a function inside the my_data class that returns my_data but with smaller size. In particular my_data of size N should have a function that returns my_data of size N-1. Do you know how to write the return type my_data<T, ...> (what should I put into the dots)?

Comment: @Bociek `my_data<T, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1>> one_smaller();`, are you going to fill this smaller instance with some data?

Comment: Thank You. Yes I will, but I am willing to use iterator for this purpose.

Comment: This is really too advanced for me right now. I hope this is my last question: How to create new object `my_data<T, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1>> x(???)` such that array s has the same numbers except the last one. In other words one is `tensor<double, 3> x(1,2,3)` and inside there would be `tensor<double, 2> y(1,2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PiotrSkotnicki !